# How can I hide the Resent-from header in Mail?

Tags: mail.app

Looking at Apple's [Mail: Show detailed message headers](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19118?locale=en_US), it sounds like I shouldn't be seeing `Resent-from` headers, because I have the View->Show message headers preference set to "Default."

The support page sounds like I should need to use Custom to ever see Resent-from.

How can I turn off the `Resent-from` header?

I also tried setting the preference to Custom... without adding any headers at all, and nothing changed.

My Mac is running OS X 10.10.5, Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

Visit https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19118?locale=en_US
The following reads:

When you view messages, you can show more fields in the message header, such as List-ID or Resent-From.
Show the headers: Choose Mail > Preferences, click Viewing, then select “Show additional message headers.”

Change the headers that are shown: Click Select Headers. To delete a field, select it, then click Remove . To add a field, click Add , then enter a field name.

Comment: That's the same support document I noted.  I don't have "Show additional message headers" under Viewing, but I can choose Show message headers: Default/Custom...  Whether i choose Default, or choose Custom with no headers at all selected in the popup, the Resent-from header is displayed.